# How to kill a process that absolutely will not die, OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, process, activity-monitor

Trying to kill an 2 unwanted process left over by a tech company. They both have to do with remote support. One is in root and the other is in user. Nothing is working.

Let's say the PID is 8005, here's what I have tried in terminal:
kill 8005, kill -9 8005, kill -KILL 8005, sudo kill 8005, sudo kill -9 8005, pkill -p -9 8005, sudo pkill -P -9 8005

And so on. You get the point.

Every time I attempt to kill, it comes back with a new PID almost instantly. The parent is launchd or kernaltask.

The tech company's response is "we have no idea." Please help!

Comment: I don't know much about OSX, but I want to try and help. Have you tried task manager, or checked the startup programs(programs that initiate on login)?

Comment: I have done both. It isn't a program, just a process, and I took it off the login list, yet it still shows up.

Comment: Mabye try apple customer support?

Comment: If it is a `launchd` task, look for its property list in one of the **LaunchAgents** or **LaunchDaemons** folders.

Comment: It's probably being kept alive by some sort of launch control. You may be able to get better help from [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). Or even [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @red_menace How can I access those folders? I'm a noob.

Comment: @joeyp As josephting said, you question is off topic for Stack Overflow and is likely more appropriate for [su] or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @joeyp those folders are in the **/Library** folder (they are also in **/System/Library**, but no one should have messed with that).

Comment: @joeyp Try running `sudo launchctl list | grep 8005` (for each of the current process IDs), and see if it comes back with something like "`8005    0    com.somebody.someprogram`". If it does, in the Finder, choose Go menu > Go To Folder, then enter "/Library/LaunchDaemons" (without the quotes), and look for a file with a similar name. That *might* be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like Launchd, Apple's launch daemon manager.

You may or may not be able to remove it with the following steps:

1. Locate the pid of the *live process*
2. Enter `launchctl list | grep PID` into terminal while replacing "PID" with the pid of the process. The PIDs will be listed on the left, if you find the culprit in the list, skip to step 4, if not, continue.
3. Enter `sudo launchctl list | grep PID` into terminal and replace "PID" with the pid of the process like you did in step 2, you will most likely find a different list of processes this time because now you are filtering through the root daemons.
4. If you did not find the process identifier in the list, then the process is not being managed by launchctl (so sorry) and the rest of this answer is pretty irrelevant. If you did, however, find the pid: Continue.
5. The process should have (on the right side) a name in the format of com.blah.blah or something similar. Make sure to remember this.

**If you found the pid in step 2:**

1. Go in Finder, Press `CMD+Shift+G` and type or paste in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and hit "Go" it will bring you to a folder and look around in that folder for a file named "com.blah.blah" aka the name of the service. If you find the file, head over to the last and final step (at the bottom)

**If you found the pid in step 4:**

1. Go in Finder, Press `CMD+Shift+G` and type or paste in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and hit "Go" it will bring you to a folder and look around in that folder for a file named "com.blah.blah" aka the name of the service. If you find the file, head over to the last and final step (at the bottom)
2. Provided you did not find the daemon in the prev step, repeat the last step only going to `/Library/LaunchAgents` after pressing "CMD+Shift+G" in Finder.

**The final step, the one that makes it real!**

At this point, you found the launch agent or daemon, and you're ready to terminate it. When you delete the file, after double checking everything, make sure that either you empty your trash immediately after, or delete it by pressing "CMD+Option+Delete", the reason why we do this, is to make sure that the file is actually gone from the OS, not just moved to the .Trashes folder. Depending on the type of service it is, you may need admin privileges, and also you may need to restart your computer.

Cheers, and good luck!

**Edit/PS:**

If any of you readers feel compelled to edit this answer/make it more clear, be my guest! I'm still learning the ropes here on SO and am doing my best to help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution. Backup all of your important files, then follow this tutorial to reset your Mac: Click [here](https://www.imore.com/how-to-prepare-mac-for-sale) to learn how to reset your mac back to original settings/data. You will lose your data, but any installed programs will dissapear and you will be able to start over.

Comment: Trying to avoid wiping my computer at all costs. I use several creative suites and to lose my settings, assets, UIs, etc would take months to recover.